# ¡Se puede subir una imagen a un lugar de un host desde un formulario con php?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy creando un lugar de control desde el que una persona pueda subir un producto a la base de datos y ya estando en la base de datos pues lo muestro en la página, pero necesito que el usuario también pueda subir una imagen junto con la descripción del producto, nombre, precio. Ya sé como subir la descripción, precio, nombre; en la parte de la imagen no sé como hacerlo ya que necesitaría que la imagen también se subiera a una carpeta que va a estar en el host para que también se pueda mostrar la imagen en la página junto con el nombre y lo demás. Mi pregunta es si alguno sabe como hacerlo y si me podría compartir documentación de como poder hacerlo, o necesariamente tengo que subir manualmente las imágenes a ala carpeta del host.

Comment: Hola Liz. Es necesario que aportes todo lo que puedas del codigo HTML, JS y PHP para poder entender y formular mejor la respuesta.

Comment: Revisa estas recomendaciones por favor: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822